# What does ('foo', 'bar')[sum(arr)%2] means?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, I came across this solution (below) to a CodeWars problem

```
def odd_or_even(arr):
    return ('even', 'odd')[sum(arr) % 2]
```

I solved mine using list comprehensions but this is one of those Pythonic concepts that are alien to my limited understanding, how does the combination of `(..)[...]` interact to each other can you explain?

Comment: Break it down into smaller pieces. What does `sum(arr)` do? What does `sum(arr) % 2` do? What do you get when you index an item of a tuple?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is simply indexing a tuple.

```
t = ('even', 'odd')
print(t[0])  # 'even'
```

**They're using the result of modulus to index into the tuple**, since `% 2` will always result in the value of 0 or 1.

I wouldn't use this though. I think they're trying to look fancy by writing it like this.

Comment: I'm sure the prompt is to return `"even"` or `"odd"` depending on the sum of elements in the given `arr`. Why do you think they're trying to look fancy?

Comment: HA! I got it makes sense, and good to know is not good practice, when I saw that I thought this may be a Pythonic way of doing things but I could not work it out, thank you

Comment: @PranavHosangadi This may just be personal opinion, but I think a conditional expression using `if sum(arr) % 2 == 0` would be a clearer way of expressing this. This seems like they're going for brevity instead of clarity.

Comment: I'm still struggling to understand how the `(...)[...]` combination works

Comment: "using the result of modulus to index into the tuple" OK got it after a second read